# How to extend Nunit to provide further environment information

Tags: .net, nunit

The NUnit TestResult.xml file contains an environment tag that provides basic info about runtimes, os-version, etc.

Is there a way to extend NUnit so that the environment tag contains more information gathered from the system?

This information will be gathered at runtime.

Thanks